# Remove Duplicate Join Columns in Hive Joins

Tags: hive, hiveql, apache-spark-sql

I am performing joins in Hive:

```
select * from
  (select * from 
      (select * from A join B on A.x = B.x) t1
  join C on t1.y = C.y) t2
join D on t2.x = D.x
```

I am getting column x cannot be resolved since A and B both contains column x. How should I use qualified name or is there a way to drop the duplicate column in Hive.

Comment: FYI, I've just open a new wish Jira ticket with a suggested solution to this issue - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-287. Let's cross our fingers that someone will pick it up.

Answer (score -1):

Because table A and table B have the column x, you must assign an alias within this select for this column

```
select * from A join B on A.x = B.x
```

Something like this

```
select A.x as x1, B.x as x2, ...
from A join B on A.x = B.x
```

Comment: The problems with this solution is I am joining 4 tables each with about 200 columns. Specifying all column names isn't feasible in my case.

Comment: Even with the current limitations this solution is not ideal. At list one table could be select with all its columns (e.g. `A.*`) with out the need to alias any of them.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something similar to the following but it means you cannot use special character in columns names.

```
set hive.support.quoted.identifiers=none;
```

---

```
select * from
  (select C.*,t1.`(y)?+.+` from 
      (select A.*,B.`(x)?+.+` from A join B on A.x = B.x) t1
  join C on t1.y = C.y) t2
join D on t2.x = D.x
```

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select#LanguageManualSelect-REGEXColumnSpecification

Answer (score -1):

I have got exactly the same problem and solution for me was to simply rename the duplicate columns by recreating the Dataframe with modified schema. Here is some sample code:

```
  def renameDuplicatedColumns(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    val duplicatedColumns = df.columns
      .groupBy(identity)
      .filter(_._2.length > 1)
      .keys
      .toSet
    val newIndexes = mutable.Map[String, Int]().withDefaultValue(0)

    val schema: StructType = StructType(
      df.schema
        .collect {
          case field if duplicatedColumns.contains(field.name) =>
            val idx = newIndexes(field.name)
            newIndexes.update(field.name, idx + 1)
            field.copy(name = field.name + "__" + idx)
          case field =>
            field
        }
    )
    df.sqlContext.createDataFrame(df.rdd, schema)
  }
```